# How to get a list of possible JSON Schema format values to use in REACT application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsonschema

We are developing a REACT application that needs to get a list of the JSON schema standard built-in formats. According to [json-schema.org reference page](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/string.html#built-in-formats) the built-in formats are as follows:

- Dates and times
- Email addresses
- Hostnames
- IP Addresses
- etc.

I'd rather if I didn't have to hardcode those values in our application, so how can we retrieve a list of those possible values programmatically?

**[EDIT]**

A clarification, we are developing a JSON schema that sets `"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema"`. This is how the app would be able to identify that we are using the current JSON Schema specification. From there we are looking for a way to load possible values for `"format"` so we can present it in the UI.

Comment: Why not hardcode them? There are only a few, and it's not a dynamic list.

Comment: Well, this is just one case, I want to be able to use the schema for fields as well, like types, and in the future, we plan on extending the schema to support custom formats. And obviously, it the reference schema is updated, I need the change to happen in one place.

Comment: JSON schema wouldn't be a proper specification if it didn't have it's own metaschema written as a JSON schema itself :-) It doesn't detail the builtin string formats though from [what I can see](https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/blob/master/meta/format-assertion.json#L12). However, the spec itself is a machine-readable XML, and you can programmatically access [the section on string formats](https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/blob/86d5739f2721ce6e54a5d6cd6729e1c80097a41e/jsonschema-validation.xml#L689) if you care. Hardcoding the list will certainly be easier!

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with `jsonschema-validation.xml`. I'm hoping there is a better way to get that list than that XML file. Although, XML is machine-readable, this file is a documentation of the standard and there is a lot more content to be parsed to extract such a list.

Comment: So are you saying different sets of formats apply to different fields?  You should update your question with more detail to be more explicit of your use case.  Currently it says, "I need a list of the available formats," which can easily be hardcoded without issue.

Comment: No, that is not what I'm saying. The immediate problem I'm facing is that to get a list of built-in format values based on the `$schema` field in the JSON Schema file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$schema` indicates the version of the specification that the schema that declares it is using.

Each version of the specification declares a (small) static set of available formats.

It's not unreasonable to hardcode these sets into a lookup by `$schema` value.  There are only 4 or 5 (if you include draft 4) values for this keyword, unless you're writing your own meta-schemas.

I've hardcoded them into my JSON Schema library, [JsonSchema.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonSchema.Net/).

---

If you're looking for an automated way to find these values, you're going to have to scan the specification documents themselves.  They're not listed in the meta-schemas, which is what you get when you navigate to the URI (not a URL) find in `$schema`.  The meta-schema just requires that `format`'s value is a string.

The specification intentionally leaves this open-ended so that people can create their own custom formats.

Comment: I'm familiar with your library, we are planning to use it for some of our components. Can you share a link to the code where you implement this?

Comment: It's here: https://github.com/gregsdennis/json-everything/blob/master/JsonSchema/Formats.cs.  I don't believe I've categorized them by spec version, though.